# How to link existing values in a 1 to many relationship in core data?

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsfetchrequest

I am trying to link a value that's already in category to the wod entity. Since I do want to call a new record for each record of wod for a category. Not sure how to do this. I was thinking of using predicate but I am not exactly sure how to link it from a fetch request.

this is what my schema looks like:

[image]

Here's the code that tries to link them together:

```
 NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    Wod *wodInfo = [NSEntityDescription
                                       insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Wods" 
                                       inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [wodInfo setValue:@"Frank" forKey:@"name"];


    NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Categories"
                                   inManagedObjectContext:context]];
    [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name == %@", @"Time"]];

    // This is the part where i am unsure, since i am not exactly sure how to link them up
      Category *category = reques
      wodInfo.category = 



    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *categories = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
Category *category = [categories lastObject];
wodInfo.category = category;
```

Be careful about your call to `[context save:&error]`. You are passing the address of the error variable, which is not initialized in your code and will refer to a random address, which might lead to weird errors in your application. I would recommend setting it to nil before passing it to the save: method.

Comment: seems like when i added categories in and i try to access that data. It returns me a NSFaultingMutableSet shouldn't it be category?

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you want each wod to be in exactly one category and you allow multiple wods to be in a single category?

Comment: If that is so then I believe you might have defined the one-to-many relationship in the opposite direction.